# How can the SQL Server cluster preferred owner be queried?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

The current SQL cluster node owner can be determined with the following query.

```
1> SELECT SUBSTRING(NodeName,1,20) as NodeName, status, status_description, is_current_owner
2> FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes;
3> GO
NodeName             status      status_description is_current_owner
-------------------- ----------- ------------------ ----------------
CORPDB001                      0 up                                1
CORPDB002                      0 up                                0
```

How can the SQL cluster preferred owner be queried?

Is this unrelated to an Availability Group?

Answer (score 1):

> How can the SQL cluster preferred owner be queried?

This isn't exposed inside of SQL Server as it's not a SQL Server property but a value for the resource in the cluster. You'll need to use powershell or WMI to obtain the values. If you'd like to have this returned in a query, it's possible to write .NET code to run the WMI/Cluster API to obtain the information.

> Is this unrelated to an Availability Group?

It's entirely a Windows cluster concept, SQL has no idea and doesn't care because the cluster takes care of all this, including failover, resource placement, etc., it's only related to AGs as they can use clustering and it does change which synchronous commit replica would be tried first on failover (doesn't mean it always will go to this one as other issues or items could occur).

Comment: Are you saying that the OS clustering is the same thing as SQL Server clustering? I am pretty sure that AG clustering is not the same thing. Is that correct? How can a mere mortal (without admin permission on the cluster) get information. My use of the PowerShell Get-Cluster* commands has been unsuccessful.

Comment: Availability Groups aren't "clustering" nor are they a "cluster". A SQL FCI is also not a "cluster" or "clustering". Windows has the cluster feature, not SQL. AGs are not required to use clustering to work (read scale). SQL FCI is required to be on a Windows Cluster. I don't know your rationale, but I highly doubt this information is needed to be queried from SQL Server. PS: `Get-ClusterOwnerNode -Group "Group_Name" | FL *`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Sean. I would like to find out if a SQL-FCI is on its primary node. It sounds like I cannot without permission on the cluster and possibly without running on the server.

Comment: There's no such thing as a primary node. There are the nodes it can run on and the nodes it currently is running on. This data should already be exposed via DMVs.